# mysql negation of like doesn't return what expected, why?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a mysql table that has 2796 entries. I'd like to select entries that doesn't contain the word SUPPR somewhere in the notes field.

If I do the following

```
SELECT * FROM `catalogues` WHERE notes LIKE "%SUPPR%"
```

It returns 266 row. But if I write what I consider the complement

```
SELECT * FROM `catalogues` WHERE notes not LIKE "%SUPPR%"
```

it returns 762 rows when I was expecting 2530 (2796-266).

How should I write the second request to get what I need?

Comment: Do you have any NULLs in the Notes field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nulls are implicitly excluded when you use `NOT LIKE`.
You handle separately:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `catalogues` 
 WHERE (notes NOT LIKE "%SUPPR%" 
        OR notes IS NULL);
```

Perhaps this was only for illustrative purposes that you used it...
DBAs and performance-buffs recommend against using `SELECT *`.